# Glitch in the carousel with the ngx-owl-carousel-o-Angular

Tags: angular

I am using the owl carousel in Angular to display different elements. The carousel is only showing from 767px below with display:block and above 767px is display:none.The problem that I am facing is that when is resize at 767px, for a second there is a glitch in the carousel. At the beginning it is messed up and after a second everything is ok. How do I fix this?

```js
   customOptions: OwlOptions = {
       loop: true,
       mouseDrag: true,
       touchDrag: true,
       pullDrag: true,
       dots: true,
       navSpeed: 700,
       navText: ['', ''],
       items: 1,
       responsive: {
         0: {
           items: 1 
         },

         319 : {
          items:1
         },
         359: {
           items: 1 
         },
   
         767:{
           items:1
         }    
       },
       nav: false
     }
  }
```

```css
@media (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .b-benefits__owlContainerBenefits {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 16.5%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  
  }
  
  
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
.b-benefits__owlContainerBenefits {
      display: none;
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="b-benefits__owlContainerBenefits">
    <owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let content of contents">
        <ng-template carouselSlide>
          <div class="b-benefits__owlImg">
            <img [src]="content.img">
          </div>
          <div class="b-benefits__owlTitle">
            {{ content.title }}
          </div>
          <div class="b-benefits__owlText">
            {{ content.text }}
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ng-container>
    </owl-carousel-o>
  </div>
```

Comment: Would you be able to create a minimum reproducible problem in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

The glitch/flicker is due to you moving from display:block to display:none, if I understand correctly. You can solve it using appropriate transition. Let me know if you need more understanding.

Comment: Do you mean instead of display  I need to use opacity 0 and 1?

Comment: @mp89 display property will be there, use transition and opacity properties so that your display none and block transitions are smooth. Also instead of display you can go for the visibility property as well which will not remove the space but just the image

Comment: For example when I put this in the media query below 767px  the glitch is still there   opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0.5s;
      display: block;  and the other one in the larger screens is    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none; . The problem is that when I remove the display the glitch is not there, but the space the owl is taking still exists and is messing up other parts of the page

Comment: Can you re-create this part of your app in stackblitz and share, I will be able to understand your exact setup and help you out.

Comment: Here is my whole code. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/upbeat-shannon-xmdf2s?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css%3A81%2C2